# How to calculate the least square coefficient error in python

Tags: python, scipy

Now I need to calculate the relation between two columns of data using least square method. I can get the equation of x and y with the function `scipy.optimize.leastsq`, the equation can be written as *y=ax+b*. The error of coefficients (*a* and *b*) is needed as well, but how to calculate them in python?
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the appropriate package to use here is [`scipy.stats.linregress`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html#scipy-stats-linregress).